# Error writing to database-Moodle

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, moodle

I have a page in Moodle where a user can add consecutive rows through JQuery and each time the Save button is clicked, the data entered in the form will be written to the database but i'm getting these error messages:

> Debug info: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
>   order) VALUES('1','Introduction Audio 1','1')' at line 1

```
INSERT INTO mobile (week,title,order) VALUES(?,?,?)
[array (
0 => 1,
1 => 'Introduction Audio 1',
2 => '1',
)]
```

**The form to which consecutive rows is being appended:**

```
 <form method="post" action="processMobileApp.php">
<br/>
<span class="add-week" style="float:right;"><input type='button' value="Add a New Week" style="font-weight:bold; font-size:17px;"/>&nbsp;</span>
<span class="add-row" style="float:right;"><input type='button' value="Add New Row" style="font-weight:bold; font-size:17px;"/>&nbsp;</span>
<span style="float:right;"><input type='submit' value="Save" style="font-weight:bold; font-size:17px;"/></span>
<br/><br/>
<table class="row-list" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<br/>
    <tr>
        <th>Week 1 Title</th><th>Order</th><th>Edit</th><th>Delete</th><th>Upload</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="title0" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="order0" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="editapp.php"><u>Edit</u></a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="deleteapp.php"><u>Delete</u></a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="uploadapp.php"><u>Upload</u></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

**The JQuery codes:**

```
<script>
jQuery(function(){
    var counter = 1;
    jQuery('span.add-row').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        counter++;
        var newRow = jQuery('<tr><td><input type="text" name="title' +
            counter + '"/></td><td><input type="text" name="order' +
            counter + '"/></td><td><a href="editapp.php"><u>Edit</u></a></td></td><td><a href="deleteapp.php"><u>Delete</u></a></td><td><a href="uploadapp.php"><u>Upload</u></a></td></tr>');
        jQuery('table.row-list').append(newRow);
    });

    var count = 2;
    jQuery('span.add-week').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        counter++;
        var newWeek = jQuery('<tr><th>Week ' + (count++) + ' Title</th><th>Order</th><th>Edit</th><th>Delete</th><th>Update</th></tr><tr><td><input type="text" name="title' +
            counter + '"/></td><td><input type="text" name="order' +
            counter + '"/></td><td><a href="editapp.php"><u>Edit</u></a></td><td><a href="deleteapp.php"><u>Delete</u></a></td><td><a href="uploadapp.php"><u>Upload</u></a></td></tr>');
        jQuery('table.row-list').append(newWeek);
    });

});

</script>
```

**The page which is handling the form data and submitting it to the database:**

```
<?php

    require_once(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))) . '/config.php');

    global $DB;

    $countWeek = 1;
    $counter = 0;
    $week = $countWeek++;
    $title = required_param("title0", PARAM_TEXT);
    $order = required_param("order0", PARAM_TEXT);

    $counter+1;

    $record2 = new stdClass();
    $record2->week = $week;
    $record2->title = $title;
    $record2->order = $order;
    $record2->displayorder = '10000';

    // Insert one record at a time.

    $lastinsertid2 = $DB->insert_record('mobile', $record2);

    if(!$lastinsertid2)
    {
        echo "Could not insert";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Successful";
    }

?>
```

Here's a screenshot of the page containing the form:

[image]

Any help please? Thanks.

Comment: `Order` and `week` are reserved words. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html They need to be backticked. Does `moodle` handle that? You first query would need to be ticked. `INSERT INTO mobile (\`week\`,title,\`order\`) VALUES(?,?,?)`

Comment: Wow i didn't think of that. Week is not a reserved word in moodle but order is. I changed it and it worked. If you could answer the question i would choose your answer as the best one.

Comment: Answer re-added I wasn't sure if moodle handled that or not so I deleted it at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order and week are reserved words. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

They need to be backticked.

```
INSERT INTO mobile (`week`,title,`order`) VALUES(?,?,?)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the xmldb editor to create the install.xml files which creates the tables for your local plugin. This will check for reserved words in the table and field names - https://docs.moodle.org/dev/XMLDB_editor

It is available via site admin -> development -> xmldb editor.

Avoid using backticks because these are database dependent. Moodle supports several databases not just mysql. It is better to continue to use the $DB->insert_record() function.